# how to disable popup behind background in windows phone 8?

Tags: user-controls, windows-phone-8

I have one silverlight user control for generating popup in in my windows phone application.
Its working fine but when i open popup at that time i want disable my background page.
Because when popup is open and user click on navigation button so he can navigate one page another page.

How to disable backgroung page when popup is open?

Comment: if you have `ApplicationBar` things are a bit tricky, otherwise you can disable current page with `this.IsEnabled = false;`

Comment: Or go with IsHitTestVisible="False" to disable the background page while showing the popup.

Comment: @vonLochow:thanks dear it will working for me...\